How to set React Canvas width and height to its parent div component (Konva Package)?
I placed a div in A4 format inside a fixed div with a height of 500px and dynamic width in a scrollable manner. The reason for the dynamic width of this div is that there is a sidebar on the screen, and this sidebar can expand and contract. So far, I don't have a problem. However, I am placing a Stage using the Konva library inside the A4 format div. This stage only accepts numeric values for width and height, so I can't provide values like "100%". I want this stage to adjust its width and height in the same way as its parent div. How can I achieve this? I tried referencing and managing it with state, but I couldn't get the exact result I wanted.


I want this stage to adjust its width and height in the same way as its parent div. How can I achieve this? I tried referencing and managing it with state, but I couldn't get the exact result I wanted.
const Home = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const myComponentRef = useRef(null)
  const { sideBarStatus } = useContext(SidebarContext)
  const [rectangles, setRectangles] = useState(initialRectangles)
  const [selectedId, selectShape] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to update width
    const updateWidth = () => {
      if (myComponentRef.current) {
        setWidth(myComponentRef.current.clientWidth)
      }
    }
    updateWidth()
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateWidth)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', updateWidth)
    }
  }, [sideBarStatus])

  const checkDeselect = e => {
    const clickedOnEmpty = e.target === e.target.getStage()
    if (clickedOnEmpty) {
      selectShape(null)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div ref={myComponentRef} style={{ height: 500, display: 'flex', width: '100%', overflow: 'auto' }}>
      <div
        style={{
          border: '2px solid black',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          position: 'relative',
          overflow: 'auto',
          width: '100%',
          height: width * Math.SQRT2
        }}
      >
        <Stage width={width} height={width * Math.SQRT2} onMouseDown={checkDeselect} onTouchStart={checkDeselect}>
          <Layer>
            {rectangles.map((rect, i) => {
              return (
                <Rectangle
                  key={i}
                  shapeProps={rect}
                  isSelected={rect.id === selectedId}
                  onSelect={() => {
                    selectShape(rect.id)
                  }}
                  onChange={newAttrs => {
                    const rects = rectangles.slice()
                    rects[i] = newAttrs
                    setRectangles(rects)
                  }}
                />
              )
            })}
          </Layer>
        </Stage>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
Home.acl = {
  action: 'read',
  subject: entitites.home
}
const initialRectangles = [
  {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    id: 'rect1'
  },
  {
    x: 150,
    y: 150,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'green',
    id: 'rect2'
  }
]
export default Home


This is a hacky fix, but anything that is compiled to html should be able to have dynamic width - check what informs the "stage" width when you inspect it in css, and then you can override that value with whatever value you want using javascript. No guarantees this will work but just an idea

This is the most basic solution that I already tried, but ofcourse doesn't work properly.



  useEffect(() => {
    const updateDimensions = () => {
      if (myComponentRef.current) {
        setWidth(myComponentRef.current.clientWidth)
        setHeight(myComponentRef.current.clientHeight)
      }
    }

    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(updateDimensions)
    if (myComponentRef.current) {
      resizeObserver.observe(myComponentRef.current)
    }

    updateDimensions()

    return () => {
      if (myComponentRef.current) {
        resizeObserver.unobserve(myComponentRef.current)
      }
    }
  }, [sideBarStatus])



I updated my useEffect as well, adding resizeObserver solve my one step late rendering problem , I don't actually know how it works exactly but I hope It works for you too guys.
